# Power BI Desktop doesn't honor percentage column type

Tags: powerbi

I've imported data (approximately 200 columns) into Power BI desktop (latest version as of 2017-08-02) and have explicitly told the app to treat a number of columns as being percentages. Within the query editor, I can verify that my values are treated as such:

[image]

When I put my data into a table, they show up as normal floats, not percentages. When I click on the exact same column as in the above picture and view it in the `Modeling` tab, Power BI shows it as being "General" format:

[image]

While I *can* go through and change the formatting here to have them all be percentages, I have already done so in the query editor! Is there a way to make PBI recognize my already specified format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Explanation:

In the query editor, you didn't actually specify any `format`. What you specified is the `data type`, so that the source data can be read correctly. Say you have a column with data like `001`, you can specify it as `text` type so you can retain the leading zero.

However, the actual formatting (i.e. data presentation) is done in your second step, because even if it's a (decimal) number, you can still format it as a percentage, with different decimal places, etc. (vice versa)

Comment: Hi @user655321 does this help solving the issue after all? If so, you can [accept this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/313506) to positively close the question.